# py file not executed when run through batch file

Tags: python

Am trying to run the batch files sequentially upon button press event.

I have solution.py & try to run via batch file solution.bat as
START /WAIT Python.exe "C:/..../solution.py

This file get executed completely & later

The Test.py have below code & am try to run from batch file test.bat as
START /WAIT Python.exe "C:/..../Test.py

```
import datetime
import time
Date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Date: %d/%m/%y")
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("Time: %H:%M:%S")
text_file = open("C:XXX.txt", "w")
text1_file = open("C:YYY.txt", "w")
import os
for file in os.listdir("C:\ZZZ"):
  if file.endswith(".txt"):
   print(file)
   cloud_file = open(file, "r")
   if '#####' in open(file).read():
       print ####
   else:
       Print $$$$$

     text_file = open("C:XXX.txt", "r")
   count = 0
   for line in text_file.readlines():
       for word in line.split():
       if word == 'Pass':
        count= count + 1
    print('Pass',count,'TC')
    text_file = open("C:XXX.txt", "r")
    count1 = 0
    for line in text_file.readlines():

for word in line.split():
    if word == 'Fail':
        count1= count1 + 1
       print('Fail',count1,'TC')

text1_file = open("C:YYY.txt", "w")

 count = 0
 for line in text1_file.readlines():
     for word in line.split():
         if word == 'Pass':
        count= count + 1
        print('Pass',count,'TC')

   text1_file = open("C:YYY.txt", "w")
   count1 = 0
   for line in text1_file.readlines():


   for word in line.split():
    if word == 'Fail':
       count1= count1 + 1
      Print('Fail',count1,'TC')
```

As sequentially, solution.bat get open & execute the solution.py file completely.  and later test.bat get opened & the code test.py get execute till creating xxx.txt & YYY.txt file only and remaining code doesn't execute.

Any help.

Comment: There are numbers syntax errors in your code, I'm not surprised it doesn't run.  I suggest you fix them first.  Which version of python are you using?  You have bare `print` and also the `print` function (not to mention the invalid `Print`).  Then there are the indentation errors ....

Comment: maybe try closing the Files you opened, or using the `with open` statement instead of just `open`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond the answer.
the path in os.listdir("C:\ZZZ") is relocated to main folder & got output.
Thanks to everyone